# CSS3's box-shadow issue

Tags: css-float, css

As I'm developing my webpage, I found an issue using the box-shadow feature.

I want to add a box-shadow to the whole wrapper of my webpage, which contains the header, nav, content and footer.

The nav and content are side by side element.

The problem is, that when I add the box-shadow to the #wrapper, it only appears on the header, as I reproduced [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6sq5/)

I was able to fix it by using the side by side elements with the display: table-cell propriety, but it ruined the rest of the page, so I'm asking how could I fix this.

Comment: You need to clear your floats, they don't take up space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` to your wrapper as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6sq5/2/). It will force your container to wrap the floated elements.

[edit] Without having to add extra markup...

Answer (score 5):

Use CSS `clear:both;` because you are floating elements to the left, check this out : [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6sq5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

instead of a wrapper you could simply make another separate  with the same size and position and give it a box shadow. change the height to whatever you want, just figure out the height of the content you want to be shadowed.

```
<style>
div.shadow {
width: 400px;
height: 100%;   
position:absolute;
z-index:-99;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px #999;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px #999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px #999; 
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="shadow></div>

<!-- everything else here-->
```